# Remove number in a tuple

Tags: python

```
def pop_at_index(seq,index):
    if index not in range(-len(seq),len(seq)):
        return seq
    lst = []
    for i in seq:
        if i != seq[index]:
            lst.append(i)
        else:
            return seq
    return tuple(lst)
```

This is my code and it suppose to work for the following cases, but it doesn't

```
print(pop_at_index((1, 2, 3), -1))#(1, 2)
print(pop_at_index((1, ), 0)) #()
print(pop_at_index((1, 3, 5, 7), 0)) #(3,5,7)
print(pop_at_index((2, 4, 6, 8, 10), -10)) #(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
print(pop_at_index((1, 3, 5, 7), -2)) #(1,3,7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `del` statement or `list.pop`.

```
def pop_at_index(seq,index):
    lst = list(seq)
    try:
        del lst[index]
    except IndexError:
        return seq
    return tuple(lst)
```

---

```
>>> print(pop_at_index((1, 2, 3), -1))
(1, 2)
>>> print(pop_at_index((1, ), 0))
()
>>> print(pop_at_index((1, 3, 5, 7), 0))
(3, 5, 7)
>>> print(pop_at_index((2, 4, 6, 8, 10), -10))
(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
>>> print(pop_at_index((1, 3, 5, 7), -2))
(1, 3, 7)
```

### Why your code does not work?

```
else:
    return seq
```

Above statement cause the function return with the `seq`. (`else` part will be executed always because there's always matched item in the sequence)